# Solr WildCard EdgeNGramFilterFactory search front and back search

Tags: solr

I'm working on implementing solr wildcard seach using EdgeNGramFilterFactory.I'm trying to implement front/back search.For example searching "format system" and "system format" to return the same results. I have configured EdgeNGramFilterFactory for front and back but only the front""format system" search is working not back "system format".Can you suggest what's the wrong or anything else i missed here?

Here is my configuration

```
<fieldType name="text_en" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
            <analyzer>
                <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" />
                <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
                <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords_en.txt" ignoreCase="true" />
                <!-- <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="English" /> -->
                <filter class="EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="15" side="front" />
                <filter class="EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="15" side="back" />
            </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example you mentioned does not fit that much since it contains terms and when you search for a term you don't need any wildcard. If you want to search for a term part, like sys for example, making NGrams looks like a good idea. I suggest you to have a look at your solr analysis page to see the results of your analyzer chain.

`EdgeNGramFilterFactory` configured with `side="front"`, having the word system as input will produce the following terms:

```
sy sys syst syste system
```

This way you can search for sys or syste and get results, even though the term you originally indexed was system.

`EdgeNGramFilterFactory` configured with `side="back"`, having the word system as input will produce the following terms:

```
em tem stem ystem system
```

This way you can search for tem or ystem and get results.

If you put them together in the same chain you have the second analyzer working on each term produced by the first one. You're basically making back NGrams out of each front NGram, which is not what you want I guess.

Better to clarify your requirements first. If you still want to generate NGrams back and front, you should do it within two different fields, then you can search on both using `edismax` parser for example.

Comment: Ok, my requirement is the search text "system format" and "format system" should return the same result.Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Also is there a way the search term "A/C" can be treated as AC and vice versa?

Comment: If you want to search only for complete words you can invert their order, that already works out of the box, you don't need NGrams. Regarding the second question, have a look at the [Solr Analyzers wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters)

Comment: thanks Javanna..! Invert search is working now but i'm facing a problem while search "W's s".The search text "W's s" doesn't return any record if i use NGrams but if i use "W's st" it is returning the correct results.. Any idea?

Comment: I think this is more a new question. It's not that handy to keep updating the same one when the problem is different. If you've solved the problem mentioned in your original question, could you please mark my answer as accepted and maybe ask a new question?